# How does WCF Message.ToString() method work?

Tags: .net, wcf, message, tostring

All of the methods on `System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message` only allow you to read the message body once, and fail with an exception if called after the message has been read.  The msdn documentation confirms that it is only possible to read a message body one.  However, if you call `ToString()` on an already read message, you appear to get back the entire soap envelope, body and all.

So in my case it would seem to be possible to access the body even after it has been read if only the methods would allow it.

Is there something I'm missing here?  Is using `ToString()` as a work-around to get the body not reliable in some situations?

In my case, I'm working on some error logging for some WCF operations and an getting the original message from `OperationContext.RequestContext.RequestMessage`.  I'm logging the message with `ToString()` because that is the only way I can find to allow  me to log the message body.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ToString *may* print the message body, but that's not guaranteed. There are many types of `Message` objects (it's an abstract class). Some of them buffer the whole body, while others only have a forward-only reader over it. The message implementations which buffer the message *may* write the body when `ToString` is called, and that's what you're seeing. But this is not guaranteed for all message types. In many cases, the body is simply written as "...stream..." when `ToString` is called.

Comment: Thanks Carlos ... I'd vote you up but don't have enough reputation :)

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to share that I have used the `message.toString` method with success for the purpose of preserving a base64 encoded string derived from a `byte[]` that is lost when a message buffer is created (the buffer is the only way to make a copy of the original message, so it was required in my code). After creating a buffer, using it to make XML, and editing the XML, I restored the base64 string using the string saved from the `toString` method. I would not recommend doing it this way, but it really was the only option in this case and I know that it will work in my particular code. That said, I generally think it should be a last resort option.

Answer (score 0):

You should create message copy then [read](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2006/07/26/this-message-cannot-support-the-operation-because-it-has-been-copied.aspx?Redirected=true). For example:

```
using (MessageBuffer messageBuffer = message.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue))
{
    Message restoredMessage = messageBuffer.CreateMessage();
    message = messageBuffer.CreateMessage();
    return MessageToString(ref restoredMessage);
}
```

RequestContext.RequestMessage is absent on one way call, so `ToString` will not work, on other way [RequestMessage.ToString()](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2008/06/accessing-the-message-inside-of-your-wcf-service-operations.html) will return message content in a string

Comment: `CreateBufferedCopy` is not allowed after the message is read either.  I'm already in my service operation and hence the message is already read.  I think the correct time to call `CreateBufferedCopy` is in a message inspector.  But I don't really want to implement a message inspector just on the off chance that I going to log the message later.  In this case I'm looking for a way to recover the message only after I encounter an error sometime during the operation, to give some context to the error logs.

Comment: As for me, message inspector is a nice choice. here is example http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/1d9d73d0-240c-46a8-853f-d7c3dfc85c6c/.

Comment: It's certainly an option ... then again `ToString` is an option unless someone knows of a reason against it, which is what I'm asking.